# How to move a folder from one repo to another repo?

Tags: svn

I tried to move one folder from one repo to another repo and followed the below steps.

To take dump of particular folder in SVN

```
svnadmin dump repo1 | svndumpfilter include repo1/branches/folder1/ > folder1.dump
```

To restore the dump

```
svnadmin load repo2 < folder1.dump
```

It got loaded successfully but I can't list the contents in the new repo. If I check out from the new repo, it works.

Can you please suggest how to list the contents of the new repo?

Thanks.

Comment: Show `sv ls -R` output

Comment: What command do you use and what error do you get?

Comment: Lazy, tried your command but not getting the list.

Comment: Alvaro, I tried the below command: svn ls svn://svnhost/repo1.

Answer (score 0):

To list content of new repo

`svn list --recursive full_url_of_repo2`

or in short:

`svn ls -R ...`

You might need to use localhost://path_to_repo2 as full url.

Does it help ?

Nicolas

Comment: I tried your command but still it is not listing. Do I need to anything after running "svnadmin load repo2 < folder1.dump" ?
Am able to check out but not list the repo... Its weird :(

Comment: Can you please write the exact command you wrote verbatim, and the output you get ?

Just an extra tip, if you have already checkout something on the same server you can use the "^" symbole to refer to your repository server, hence `svn list ^/trunk` will list everthing that are on trunk of the repository.