# how to copy/move/clone folders from one repo to another repo's root

Tags: git, gitlab

I want to move folders under a repo to the root of another repo like below

> ### repo1
>
> -->folder0 (git@git...net:/folder0.git)
>
> > -->folder1
> >
> > -->folder2
> >
> > -->folder3

to

> ### repo2 (same gitlab as repo1)
>
> -->folder1
>
> -->folder2
>
> -->folder3

i.e. all the folders (1,2,3) should be in the root of repo2 so that all folder (1,2,3) can go directly under (git@git...net:)

**What i have tried is**

1. is copy folder by folder that looses history
2. some links here [How to move a folder from one repo to another repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21827934/how-to-move-a-folder-from-one-repo-to-another-repo)

What i need is - copy all folders under the subfolders and move it to the root

Answer (score 0):

If it's pushed in repo1 you can cherry pick git from repo2.

in `.git/config` of repo2 add :

```
[remote "copyFrom"]
    url = git@github.com:{repo1Url}
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/copyFrom/*
```

once you add the "copyFrom", repo2 have a new remote so you can fetch and cherry pick the commit from repo1 (like it was `origin` )

```
git fetch copyFrom 

git cherry-pick -xn {commit-from-repo1}
```

Please notice that if the code in repo1 is very different from repo2 and the commit of the folders hold other changes in the code this solution can be messy

Comment: thanks, this is a nice way, i found a nice way to do the same. - https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.15/user/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/

Answer (score 0):

I found an easier way in the below link

https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.15/user/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/

This worked for me. The issues i faced in the steps given above are

1. in this command `git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter FOLDER-NAME  BRANCH-NAME` 
   The `BRANCH-NAME` is **master**
2. if the last step fails when committing due to protection issue follow - https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html